# Python pandas how to group and match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, ranking-functions

Let's say we have two tables, `trans` and `product`. Hypothetically the `trans` table consists of over a billion rows of purchases bought by users.

I am trying to find paired products that are often purchased together(purchased on the same date) by the same user, such as wine and bottle openers, chips and beer, etc..

I am trying to find the top five paired products and their names.

trans and prod dataframe :-

```
trans = {'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,1,5,5,6,6,6],
        'productID':[11,22,11,22,33,77,11,77,88,11,22,77],
        'Year':['2022-01-01','2022-01-01','2020-01-05','2020-01-05','2019-01-01','2019-01-01','2020-01-07','2020-01-08',
                '2020-01-08','2021-06-01','2021-06-01','2021-06-01']}
trans = pd.DataFrame(trans)
trans['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(trans['Year'])
trans


product = {'productID':[11,22,33,44,55,77,88],
        'prodname':['phone','Charger','eaphones','headset','scratchgaurd','pin','cover']}
product = pd.DataFrame(product)
product
```

My code till now where was trying to Rank the items with same ID and Year and then try to get the product names.

```
transprod = pd.merge(trans,product,on='productID' , how='inner')
transprod


transprod['Rank'] = transprod.groupby('ID')['Year'].rank(method = 'dense').astype(int)
transprod = transprod.sort_values(['ID','productID','Rank'])
transprod
```

Desired Output:

```
Product 1 | Product 2 | Count
phone       charger      3
Charger      pin         1
eaphones     pin         1
pin         cover        1
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the transactions table by ID (and date) and list all product pairs for each order. `itertools.combinations` is useful here. By taking the set over an order first, you can ignore multiple equal items.

Since it does not matter in which order a pair appears, you could then construct a flat list of all the pairs and use a `collections.Counter` instance to count them. Sorting each pair first makes sure that you can disregard the order of items within a pair.

The product table can be transformed into a dictionary for easy lookup. This will provide a way to add the product names to the table of results.

```py
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

pairs_by_trans = trans.groupby(['ID', 'Year'])['productID'].agg(
                       lambda x: list(combinations(set(x), 2)))
pairs_flat = [tuple(sorted(pair)) for row in pairs_by_trans for pair in row]

counts = Counter(pairs_flat)
top_counts = pd.DataFrame(counts.most_common(5),
                          columns=['pair', 'count'])

prodname = {k: v for k, v in product.values}
top_counts['names'] = top_counts['pair'].apply(lambda x: (prodname[x[0]], 
                                                          prodname[x[1]]))

top_counts
```

```
    pair    count   names
0   (11, 22)    3   (phone, Charger)
1   (33, 77)    1   (eaphones, pin)
2   (77, 88)    1   (pin, cover)
3   (11, 77)    1   (phone, pin)
4   (22, 77)    1   (Charger, pin)
```

Comment: Hi @Arne by products purchased together, we mean bought on the same date , as this solution looks great can we also add a check to match the dates by any chance ?

Comment: Sure, you can pass a list of column names to the `groupby` method. I have edited the answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works perfectly fine for me

```
transprod = pd.merge(trans,product,on='productID' , how='inner')



transprod['Rank'] = transprod.groupby('ID')['Year'].rank(method = 'dense').astype(int)
transprod = transprod.sort_values(['ID','productID','Rank'])


def checkprod(x):
    v1  = (x['Rank']==x['Rank'].shift(-1))
    
    return (x[v1 | v1.shift(1)])

out = transprod.groupby('ID').apply(checkprod).reset_index(drop=True)

pairs = out.groupby(['ID','Rank'])['prodname'].agg(
                       lambda x: list(combinations(set(x), 2)))


Counter(list(itertools.chain(*pairs)))
```